# Deleting an array of pointers to functions?

Tags: c++, new-operator

Here is what I've copied from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/library/kewsb8ba%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) about `new` operator:

> The `new` operator cannot be used to allocate a function, but it can be
>   used to allocate pointers to functions. The following example
>   allocates and then frees an array of seven pointers to functions that
>   return integers.
>
> ```
> int (**p) () = new (int (*[7]) ());
> delete *p;
> ```

Well there is nothing strange with first line, it allocates an array of pointers to functions, but I just don't understand how the second deletes that array? I think it should be:

```
delete[] *p;
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: No, it should be `delete[] p` (no asterisk).

Comment: and how "delete *p;" is valid? that's what I can't figure out

Comment: @codekiddy, `*p` in this case is 0 (i.e. NULL), therefore `delete *p` is a no-op. If you had initialized the first element of the array to point to a function, the behavior of the program would have been undefined (it would have probably crash your program).

Comment: yeah I screwed up(don't know how to edit lol) sorry :/

Comment: If you quote something, use the quote-formatting and provide a link to the source (I did that for you).

Comment: Incidentially, the MSDN page seems to have the correct code, too.

Comment: @Björn Pollex, thanks I'll try to remember that :)

Comment: @Damon No, that's a bug in the documentation. Correct it `delete[] p`

Comment: @Vjo: There seem to be several different versions of that same page to which you're redirected randomly? I looked at the link an hour ago and it very clearly said `delete[]` -- really, I'm not hallucinating. Now, 30 seconds ago, I saw your comment, said "WTF?" to myself, and looked again, and now it says `delete*`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly speaking the right answer was written in the **avakar's** comment.
The right code is

```
delete[] p;
```

`delete *p;` is incorrect for two reasons:

1. we must use `delete[]` for all dynamically allocated arrays. Using
   `delete` will cause an undefined behaviour.
2. pointers to static and member functions cannot be deleted

Comment: I think your second point is worded unluckily, although you're right that `delete *p` is wrong on two accounts. Pointers to <whatever> can certainly be deleted, supposed they were allocated. A pointer is, after all, just that, a pointer. However `delete *p` does not delete the pointer, but tries to delete the pointed-to-function.

Comment: Though admittedly my wording is not much better... since of course not the pointer is deleted, but what's pointed too. So probably "delete takes a pointer and *p isn't a pointer" is the wording that should be correct.

Comment: thanks for answer Dmitry, also big thanks to others for answering!

Answer (score 2):

If we add a typedef,

```
typedef int (*FPtr)();
```

the `new` statement can be rewritten as

```
FPtr *p = new FPtr[7];
```

so this is obvious that the resource should be released with

```
delete[] p;
```

as explained by others.

---

BTW, the MSDN page for VS 2008 and above does use the correct code.

```
int (**p) () = new (int (*[7]) ());
delete [] p;
```

Comment: This might be because I added the link by googling, and thus might have linked a different version than the one the OP was quoting. My bad.

Comment: @codekiddy: It says `delete[]` in the [2008 US version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/library/kewsb8ba%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: this version doesn't: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kewsb8ba%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: let's try again [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kewsb8ba%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)